# Student books like English "Round-up" but for teaching/learning German language

Tags: book

I'm looking for the books like English "Round-up" to teach children German. I'm 100% sure that books like these exist but I just don't know about them. Could you help, please?

More concrete: I need studentbooks to teach  German language to children aged from 7-15. Books for grammar and speech. Books with high scores and that you can recommend and you would use for the same reasons.

Comment: Can you make this question answerable by people who do not know the "Round-Up" books?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm incompetent in asking questions. I added additional info. I hope this will help.

Comment: I would recommend entering *Schulbücher Englisch* in your preferred search engine. *Schulbücher* (text books for students at school) are quite commonly made for learners aged 7-15. Practically everything you find being issued by the large *Schulbuch* publishers will be "high score". (Although of course 7-15 years is a pretty wide age bracket. And unless you do not narrow down your criteria a bit, as "high scores and can be recommended" is rather unspecific.)

Comment: My suggestions would differ based on the larger context. What is the native language of the children? For how long have they been learning German? Are the books also meant for self-study? Are you teaching in a classroom setting with dozens of students or are you teaching only a few? (And I also don't know the Round-up-books [being German]).

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the educational publishers in your home country. It is their job to offer such books. You may try to search German publishers with this search engine here: https://www.derdiedaf.com/unterrichtsmaterial/kinder-jugendliche/a1/ or you search the internet for these keywords "deutsch als fremdsprache arbeitsblätter jugendliche kinder".